# Improve separation of view and logic

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, partial-views

I'm designing some web app, I went for some _layout.cshtml, which fragment:

```
//some html
<h4>Your account</h4>
@{ Html.RenderPartial("UserMenu"); }
```

is responsible for rendering menu views. It has 3 possible states - logged in as admin, logged in as mere user, not logged. I made this partial view like this:

```
@if (User.IsInRole("Admin"))
{
    @:Admin menu
}
else
{
    if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        @:Normal menu
    }

    else
    {
        @Html.ActionLink("Login", "Logon", "Account");
    }
}
```

But I'm not satisfied with this solution as it has poor separation of logic and view. How do you suggest to improve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But I'm not satisfied with this solution as it has poor separation of logic and view

I don't agree. For me this kind of logic is perfectly acceptable in the view. You could have written a custom HTML helper which could be used like this in your Layout:

```
<h4>Your account</h4>
@Html.Menu()
```

and put the logic in the helper instead of using this partial. And if you decide to implement it here's how it might look:

```
public static class HtmlExtensions
{
    public static IHtmlString Menu(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper)
    {
        var user = htmlHelper.ViewContext.HttpContext.User;
        if (user.IsInRole("Admin"))
        {
            return new HtmlString("Admin menu");
        }

        if (user.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            return new HtmlString("Normal menu");
        }

        return htmlHelper.ActionLink("Login", "Logon", "Account");
    }
}
```

Comment: Certainly not, but personally I don't like constructions like if-else(if-else) as I feel it as view is taking responsibility for duties which shouldn't be taken. I was rather thinking of some helper which will select proper PartialView from possible 3 - what do you think?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see there any major problems, if you have validations & authorization checks in the server side.

The "logic" you have there is not a business logic, so it's acceptable to have `if` statements.

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility would be something like this:

Define a base class or interface, say "UserState". Define three classes that extend this class, each representing a different state of the user, such as UserAdmin, UserNormal, UserAnonymous.

Have a method defined in your model logic like so:

```
public void UserState GetUserState(User user)
{
    if (user.IsInRole("Admin"))
    {
        return new UserAdmin(user);
    }
    if (user.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        return new UserNormal(user);
    }
    return new UserAnonymous();
}
```

You could perhaps invoke it from a html helper:

```
public static UserState GetUserState(this HtmlHelper html)
{
    var user = html.ViewContext.HttpContext.User;
    return MyModelLogic.GetUserState(user);
}
```

Then, in _layout.cshtml:

```
@{ var userState = Html.GetUserState(); }
@Html.DisplayFor(_ => userState)
```

Finally, you can then implement a separate display template for each class that inherits UserState. That way, you have a separate view for each state of the user, and the logic that decides which gets used has nothing to do with the presentation layer.